# vuejs how can i pass my data back to view please

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Can any one assist with why i cant get my array into the following please

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr v-if="email" v-for="mail in email" :key="">
                <td>{{ allMyUsers.id  }}</td>
                <td>{{ allMyUsers.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ allMyUsers.email }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm calling my results as follows, i can see that the array is passed through my log (I think) but really strugging to understand my problem

Script:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

export default {

```
computed: {
  allMyUsers () {
    return !this.$store.getters.alluser ? false : this.$store.getters.alluser
  },
},
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('allUsers')
}
```

}

My code for getting the data is as follows and definately returns the data as I can see it in the log, just not sure if im passing it out

```
    allUsers ({commit, state}) {
  if (!state.idToken) {
    return
  }
  globalAxios.get('/users.json')
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data
      const allUsers = []
      for (let key in data) {
        const user = data[key]
        user.id = key
        allUsers.push(user)
     }
    commit('storeUser', allUsers)
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

My getter is as follows

```
   getters: {
    alluser (state) {
      return state.allUsers
    },
  }
```

})

Any support very much appreciated as im new to vue so very much still learning

---

Many thanks for the help so far, I have tried to follow your guidance but nothing is returned and i now have no errors

my updated code is as follows, I was sure I d followed the guidance you kindly provided

HTML:

```
        <tr v-if="myuser" v-for="myuser in allMyUsers" :key="">
          <td>{{ myuser.email }}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {

    computed: {

      allMyUsers () {
        return !this.$store.getters.myuser ? false : this.$store.getters.myuser
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('allMyUsers')
    }
  }
</script>
```

GETTER:

```
myuser (state) {
  return state.myuser
},
```

Function:

```
allMyUsers ({commit, state}) {
     if (!state.idToken) {
       return
     }
        globalAxios.get('/users.json' + '?auth=' + state.idToken)
          .then(res => {
            const data = res.data
            const myusers = []
            for (let key in data) {
              const myuser = data[key]
              myuser.id = key
              myusers.push(myuser)
           }

        commit('storemyuser', myusers)
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

And finally my MUTATION:

```
storemyuser (state, myuser) {
  state.myuser = myuser
},
```

Thankyou again for your assistance, you guys really are great at helping newbes like me learn

Comment: Do not have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your `v-for` loop is not good, `email` property is not defined in your component, you only defined a computed `allUsers` property (with getters from your store). It's this one you need to use :

```html
<tr v-if="user" v-for="user in allUsers" :key="">
  <td>{{ user.id  }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi sovalina, thanks so much for your help so far, I have made some changes but get no error now and assume its by bad syntax but just cant figure it out... changes added below my original post..... thanks again for any help you can offer